# How do I split a 32 inch display into top half advertising screen, bottom to run an application

Tags: windows, screen, resolution

I have this project, which requires to split a 32 inch screen to run two application. The top half shows advertising, the bottom half runs a separate application. Both are windows apps. The display is in portrait mode.  Can you anyone help.

Comment: How are you creating the application? What kind of application is it? Are you using winforms or is it a web application? Are you using .Net framework? We need more information.

Comment: Hmm, make sure the uninstaller works well.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It lets you move application windows around on the screen and even (if you're evil) mark them to always float on top.

Comment: Depending on the operating system.  You might be able to leverage Windows 7's ability to dock windows.  I don't know if you can access the window docking feature through an API.  You could also in theory use a program to remember the settings.